# FileNotFoundError but a neighbor file can find it

Tags: python, networking, file-not-found, ciscoconfparse

Trying to use Cisco confparse. I have two .py files and two .txt files. One python file can parse both .txt files while the other gets FileNotFoundError on parsing both .txt files. All of the files are in the same location:

```
/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing//test.py
/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing//test2.py
/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing//exampleSwitch.txt
/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing//exampleSwitch2.txt
```

test.py works:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

# Parse the config into objects
confprse = CiscoConfParse('exampleSwitch.txt')

# Iterate over all the interface objects
for intf_obj in confprse.find_objects('^interface'):
    print("cisconfparse object: ")
    print(intf_obj)
    print(intf_obj.text)
```

and test2.py doesnt:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse


confprse = CiscoConfParse('exampleSwitch2.txt')
```

The error is:

```
[FATAL] CiscoConfParse could not open 'exampleSwitch2.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ciscoconfparse/ciscoconfparse.py", line 233, in __init__
    f = open(config, **self.openargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'exampleSwitch2.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing/test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    confprse = CiscoConfParse('exampleSwitch2.txt')
  File "/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ciscoconfparse/ciscoconfparse.py", line 308, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError
RuntimeError
```

Not sure what the problem is.

current permissions:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  8 christian  staff   272 Jul 14 09:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 christian  staff   170 Jul 14 09:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 christian  staff   238 Jul 14 10:20 .idea
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff   332 Jul 13 10:26 exampleSwitch.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 christian  staff   875 Jul 14 09:06 exampleSwitch2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff  1402 Jul 14 09:01 test.py
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff   167 Jul 14 09:54 test2.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 christian  staff   204 Jul 14 08:46 venv
```

Created a new file within PyCharm "exampleSwitch4.txt" Here are the permissions:

```
(venv) (base) Christians-MBP:Testing christian$ ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  9 christian  staff   306 Jul 15 12:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 christian  staff   170 Jul 15 12:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 christian  staff   238 Jul 15 12:04 .idea
-rw-r--r--@ 1 christian  staff   332 Jul 13 10:26 exampleSwitch.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff   875 Jul 14 10:47 exampleSwitch3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff   575 Jul 15 12:04 exampleSwitch4.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 christian  staff  1402 Jul 14 09:01 test.py
-rw-r--r--@ 1 christian  staff   167 Jul 15 12:04 test2.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 christian  staff   204 Jul 14 08:46 venv
```

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import os; print(os.listdir('/Users/christian/Desktop/Networking/Testing'))`

Comment: @JohnGordon ['.idea', 'exampleSwitch.txt', 'exampleSwitch2.txt', 'test.py', 'test2.py', 'venv']

Comment: Are you sure the code for `test2.py` is accurate as shown?  Did you cut-n-paste it into the question, or did you type it manually?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is accurate, I copied and pasted it. Now I did initially create the file in a different folder, and then moved it over to this one if that helps.

Comment: Maybe @Stefan is right -- what are the permissions on the two txt files?

Comment: @JohnGordon  Im not sure how to check the permissions

Comment: Go to that directory in a terminal window and type `ls -la`

Comment: @JohnGordon actually looks like a windows computer if you use windows type "dir" into the directory in the terminal.

Comment: @JohnGordon Added them to OP

Comment: The `@` sign next to `exampleSwitch2.txt` tells me something is odd about that file.  The manual says that it means the file has "extended attributes", and I'm not sure exactly what those are.  Would it be convenient to remove the file altogether and recreate it from scratch?

Comment: @JohnGordon Im using a mac. And I just tried deleting it and replacing it. It still has the same error

Comment: How are you creating the file?  Are you copying it from some other directory, or are you creating it from scratch with a text editor?

Comment: @JohnGordon I create it in TextEdit, and then I copy it over. I wasn't seeing an option in PyCharm to create a .txt file

Comment: Why do you need to "copy it over" at all?  Why not just create it in that directory in the first place?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something tricky in the creation of the file that's causing the issue.  I see that the first file `exampleSwitch.txt` does not have an `@` next to it.  However you created that file, can you create `exampleSwitch2.txt` in the same way?

Comment: @JohnGordon Okay, so this time I created a new .txt file within PyCharm by right-clicking on the 'Testing' folder and then selecting "new>File". It still didnt work and Ill update what I saw in permissions in the OP. What I have noticed, is that test.py can run fine with all of the .txt files, while test2.py cannot. For some reason it cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the executing User has the right permissions.

Comment: The error is "file not found", not "permission denied", so this likely isn't the cause.

Comment: @Stefan How would I check the permissions?

Comment: @thebigstapla if you execute the script with your normal user then just check if you can open the file

Comment: @Stefanxyz Yes i can manually open the file outsside the script